# Copy master branch data into other branch

Tags: git, github

I have a project with a master branch and a second_branch. The data in the two branches is different and I want to copy the data from the master branch into second_branch and then update second_branch on GitHub. How can I do that?

The status of second_branch is:

> This branch is 3 commits ahead, 1 commit behind master

Comment: You mean you want to discard the changes in second_branch and make it identical to master?

Comment: @minitech Yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git reset` to point a branch to a different commit. So, on `second_branch`,

```
git reset --hard master
```

Then `git push -f` to update GitHub.